# MVC Link HTML Encode

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following in my view:

```
 <td><a href="/Crs/Main/?Txt=How does <i>this</i> work>How it works</a></td>
```

I believe I need to use HTML Encode. How do I do it in this situation.

Comment: Where is the href value's closing tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to both HTML encode (to preserve the HTML tags) as well as URL encode (to encode the spaces so that it doesn't truncate the `Txt` variable to be `How does`

```
<a href="/Crs/Main/?Txt=@Url.Encode(Html.Encode("How does <i>this</i> work"))">How it works</a>
```

Server-side, then decode the value:

```
var txtValue = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(txt))
```

Alternatively you can use the `@Html.ActionLink` helper (as mentioned in another answer), which will automatically URL encode your parameter, but you will still need to either explicitly HTML encode the value like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("How it works", "Main", "Crs", new { Txt = Html.Encode("How does <i>this</i> work") }, null)
```

Or you can tell the action to trust all input by decorating it with the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute, which will negate the need to explicitly HTML encode your parameter, but could be a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Html.ActionLink` whiich always encode link text using HttpUtility.Encode.

```
@Html.ActionLink("How it works", "Main", "Crs", new { @Txt = "How does <i>this</i> work"}, new { })
```

Alternatively you can use `Url.Action` to form the link and for the parameter you have to pass to action, construct it using `Html.HtmlDecode` and later append after link.

Comment: With `Html.ActionLink` the element will be created as `<a href="/Crs/Main?Txt=How%20does%20%3Ci%3Ethis%3C%2Fi%3E%20work">How it works</a>` which encodes the txt parameter.